# AFTER UPDATE trigger using an aggregate from the updated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, triggers

I'm having trouble with an update trigger.  I want the trigger to set `Quarterbacks.Yards` equal to the sum of Wide receiving yards if they're on the same team.

```
create trigger T_Receiving_Passing
on NFL.Widereceivers
after update
as
begin
declare
@receivingyards int,

select @receivingyards = sum (Widereceivers.Yards) from NFL.Widereceivers
update NFL.Quarterbacks
set Quarterbacks.Yards = @receivingyards
where Quarterbacks.Team = Widereceivers.Team
end
```

At the end of the statement, `Widereceivers.Team` is underlined in red, and it is causing errors.  I get this same error whenever I try to reference a column in another table without naming the table in a `from` clause.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: When editing a code block, you can highlight the whole thing and click in `{}` in the toolbar, or ctl-k to indent the block 4 spaces preserving whitespace.

Comment: How do you determine which team you are updating? Your `select` has no `GROUP BY`, so therefore you're getting the total `SUM()` for all rows. Is that supposed to be grouped by team?  What RDBMS is this for -- it looks more or less like MySQL.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Where Would I place the group by statement?

Comment: And yes, it is supposed to be grouped by team.  Would I place that in the statement where I give the variable value?

Comment: Depends - do you intend to update _all_ of the teams each time? If so, you need a `GROUP BY` and can probably do this with just the `UPDATE` and not need the variable or `SELECT`.  Or do you only intend to update the one team related to whatever row changed in `Widereceivers`?

Comment: I will be adding receivers from different teams, and I only want to update those the statistics for those quarterbacks who's yardage will be affected.

Comment: What I want to do is set each quarterback's passing yards equal to the sum of all his receivers receiving yardage.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you should be able to do this without the `SELECT` statement or its variable and instead use a more complex `UPDATE` statement joining on the special `inserted` table which holds the new values from the update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Receiving_Passing
ON NFL.Widereceivers
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  UPDATE NFL.Quarterbacks
  -- Get the SUM() in a subselect
  SET Quarterbacks.Yards = (SELECT SUM(Yards) FROM Widereceivers WHERE Team = inserted.Team) 
  FROM 
    NFL.Quarterbacks
    -- Join against the special inserted table
    JOIN inserted ON Quarterbacks.Team = inserted.Team
GO
```

[Here is a proof of concept](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f02c7/1)

In your original attempt, you hoped to use a `SELECT` query first to populate a scalar variable. In an `UPDATE` statement however, you can use a subselect that returns exactly one column of exactly one row inside the `SET` clause to retrieve a new value.

Since your requirement was to use an aggregate `SUM()` it isn't as straightforward as assigning a value directly from the `inserted` like `SET Yards = inserted.Yards`. Instead, the subselect produces the aggregate sum limited to just the `Team` used in the `inserted` row.

As far as the `inserted/deleted` tables go, [review the official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx). I have not worked with SQL Server regularly for a few years but if I recall correctly, the `inserted` table must occur in the `FROM` clause which implies it will usually need to be `JOIN`ed in. In your `UPDATE` statement, `inserted` is needed in both the subselect and the outer query, so it was joined in the outer one.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What did it do instead? What result? Any error message?

Comment: I modified the trigger I had created and I used the one you wrote.  I then updated the receiver's stats, adding fifty yards to all receivers on DEN, PIT, and SEA.  However, when I looked at the quarterback's stats their yardage had increased way too much.

Comment: Actually it started to work.  In the subselect I just had to specify Widereceivers.Yards and Widereceivers.Team.  It worked the way I want it to.  Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I have limited experience with subselects, and I would have never thought to do that.  Can I ask what exactly the subselect is doing?

Comment: If I want to reference the insert/delete table in any of my update statements, will I need to do a join?